# c++ chrono unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, c++11

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point start;
//1 second passes
std::cout << (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()-start).count();
```

The above code, after 1 second, in Visual Studio 2012 gives me `10000000` but on gcc 4.8.2 gives me `100000000`.

Changing the last line to `std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()-start).count();` works as expected and gives me the same result on both compilers.

How is this possible?

Comment: The units of these values are not fixed. You cannot rely on them being seconds.

Comment: chrono::high_resolution_clock is system dependent.

Comment: But it's in the standard library, how it can be system dependent?

Comment: @Luka because the standard allows it? Some/most systems have longer tick periods on their system clock than their high-res clock. Any specific reason you're purposely using two different clocks for what appears to be a simple duration calculation? (and the opening paragraph of the description of [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) on cppreference is does a pretty colic job emphasizing the implementation *dependence* of that specific clock type).

Comment: 'High resolution' on WINXX in this case has a resolution of 100ns but on Linux, again in this case, it has a 10ns resolution. (corrected for dyslexia)

Comment: Is there any place I can learn more about the system dependent libraries of c++?

Comment: Josuttis is awesome - "The C++ Standard Library" 2nd edition.

Comment: @Luka There is a lot of implementation defined stuff in the standard library, usually the first place to check is some kind of reference, like [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock), if what you are looking for is not explicitly stated, chances are it's implementation defined. After that it's searching the web and/or diving into the C++ standard.

Comment: Bear in mind that VS2012 standard library implements `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` with 1ms precision only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock

> Class std::chrono::high_resolution_clock represents the clock with the smallest tick period provided by the implementation.

So, GCC has a different resolution to VS.

The standard allows this because different systems have different requirements for time accuracy.

As you have already discovered there are methods of converting such a clock to a known resolution.